# How to easily change the default color of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to Android, and trying to do some design on my first application, I changed the background ! and Now I want to change the color of the listView ( Blue ), Onclick, and when sliding up/Down.

Is it possible to change on the XML file, or I have to do programmatically.

here is a screenshot to make things clear :

[image]

I put as background for the list view this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/Orange"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I get this :

[image]

So this is not what i'm looking for, I want only to change the default blue color

Comment: you just need a selector as background for the row

Answer (score 1):

create one selector file,

`/res/drawable/list_selectr.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/list_item_pressed"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/list_item_normal" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

And apply this xml as the background to the root tag of `listview` items xml.

Such as,

```
<RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/list_selector .../>"
```

Comment: @Strange90 `<item android:state_pressed="true" >` will change the color when you click the item.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set list background attribute of ListView in xml

android:background="#your_color"

Comment: I don't wanna change the background color, I want to change the Onclick color

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution for this, it's more simple that the solutions I found :

Just add this to your ListView in your xml file : `android:listSelector="Yourcolor"`

if you want the color for only "on focus" use a separated xml file :
`android:listSelector="Yourbackground"`

XML Example :

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
<shape>
<solid android:color="@color/Orange"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item>
<shape>
<solid android:color="@color/Transparent" />
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```